# Convert from type Nullable in Julia

Tags: julia

The response from a call to the blpapi in Julia is type Array{Nullable,n}. I'd like to be able to work with the data (plot it, math operate on it). How can I get around each data point being type Nullable? Is there a way to convert to Float64?

Comment: Suppose `v` is the Nullable Array, then `get.(v)` should be a regular Array of the values (of course, there should not be `#NULL` values in `v`)

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dan Getz for this.

"Suppose v is the Nullable Array, then get.(v) should be a regular Array of the values (of course, there should not be #NULL values in v)."

Comment: If the array may have `#NULL`s in it, you can also use `get.(v, d)` with some reasonable default value `d`.

Comment: A good default is NaN for Float64's - this is respected and treated in many downstream packages in a sensible way.